# Place of words in sentence below

Tags: meaning

> I couldn’t find my glasses’s  box which  was given by my father.

In this sentence “which “ modifed “box”  . We understand that box was given by my father.

> I couldn’t find box of my glasses which  was given by my father.

And in this sentence which modified ”glasses.

I know these sentences have different meaning . But I wonder if second sentence can be understood in two different way.I mean can it mean either glasses or box may have given by my father ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both sentences the relative clause "which..."  modifies "box", though it may be hard (for a native speaker) to parse. We know this because of the verb "was".  This is a singular verb, so must refer to the box and not the plural "glasses".

In other sentences there could be ambiguity:

> I couldn't find my pens' lids, which were green.

It is ambiguous whether the lids were green or the pens were green.  In speech it is even harder because there is no difference between the sound of "pen's" and "pens'". It is hard to parse, because ususally we put a modifier phrase as close as possible to the word that is being modified.

This ambiguity can be played for a joke:

> This is the dog of my cousin, who chases cats and barks all night!

(Ambiguity, is it the dog, or the cousin, who chases cats?)

If you wanted to refer to the glasses you would need a plural

> I couldn't find my box of glasses, which were given to me by my father.